# API dialog flow assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, assistant

Hello I’ve been searching around and found this community is good for asking about Dialogflow or Api.ai , my question was how would I be able to intergrate my assistant into a service that gives it a voice so it can speak back to the user because I was looking to make a google like assistant so I could put the assistant into a raspberry pi give it a mic and speaker and it can be an assistant thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Google Assistant to a Raspberry Pi using the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/).  You could then [create a app for the Google Assistant with Dialogflow](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app) and invoke it by saying "OK Google talk to `name of your app`".

Comment: is it working for you? I kee getting "<yourAppName> isn't supported on this device"